# Checking time in devices without automatic date and time option (Other than using time servers)

Tags: android

My android app requires it that the users' devices are set to the right time. I'm currently doing this by checking if Automatic Date and Time option is enabled in the settings, but I'm getting complaints from users who don't have the option in their devices. Using time servers is an option but I'd have to settle for approximate values, considering the network delay on slow connections. I need help with another solution. Maybe the method android system uses to get the right time? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

An out of the box solution will be to experiment with GPS time. That'd require your app to have GPS access, and you can get the time from GPS.

Comment: Thanks, but as you said, that would be a problem if there's no GPS. I'm looking for a somewhat universal solution.

Comment: There has to be a source that gives you time. It'll need to be either system time, which can be wrong if the user sets it incorrectly and there is no automatic update as you mentioned. Else you need to use timeservers or GPS time. What exactly is the issue with Time servers besides latency? There can be ways to mitigate it, as you can read time from timeserver once and then run an internal clock within you app that counts seconds. Will that do?

Comment: Could give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion. :)